# Need help getting rid of bottom scroll bar

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have been trying to get rid of the horizontal scrollbar in my code. I am creating a personal portfolio page. I have looked at all my widths and I don't think that's the issue. It might be my media queries. I am new to coding and I am sorry if this isn't a good question. I have tried researching and found vmin vh vw vmax and such but when applied to all the widths, it doesn't appear to affect the scroll bar.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=PT+Sans&family=Roboto:wght@400;500&family=Ubuntu&display=swap');
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 62.5%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(180deg, #001219, #005F73, #0A9396, #0B9669);
}

body {
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  font-family: Roboto, PT Sans, Ubuntu;
  text-size-adjust: 80%;
}

#navbar {
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, #001219, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.navbar-links {
  text-decoration: none!important;
  color: #F2E9E4;
}

ul {
  list-style: none!important;
}

nav>ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.invisible-para {
  opacity: 0%;
}

#welcome-section {
  color: #CA6702;
  text-shadow: 2px, 2px;
  text-align: center;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 5vmin;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 13.5em;
}

.welcome-header {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 20px black;
}

.welcome-para {
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 20px black;
}

.project-image {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.projects-header {
  padding-top: 3rem!important;
  padding-bottom: 2rem;
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 3.5rem;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 20px black;
  color: #CA6702;
}

#projects {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.project-tile {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #001219;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 20px;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-family: PT Sans;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: #94D2BD;
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 300px;
  padding: 1rem;
  margin: 8vh 10vw 0 10vw;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 20px;
}

.grid-container {
  width: 100%;
  display: grid!important;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 2rem;
  align-self: center;
  text-align: center;
}

#contact {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 3em;
  height: auto;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 20px;
}

#contact-header {
  font-size: 8vmin;
  padding: 0 0 2em 0;
}

div>ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

#profile-link {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  font-family: Ubuntu;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 4vmin;
  background-color: #94D2BD;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 8px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 20px;
}


/*MEDIA QUIERIES BELOW*/

@media (max-width: 800px) {
  .grid-container {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  }
}

@media (max-width:400px) {
  #welcome-section {
    bottom: 25em;
  }
}


/*MEDIA QUEIRIES ABOVE*/
```

```html
<p class="invisible-para" id="welcome-section"></p>
<nav id="navbar">
  <ul>
    <li><a class="navbar-links" href="#welcome-section">Welcome</a></li>
    <li><a class="navbar-links" href="#projects">Projects</a></li>
    <li><a class="navbar-links" href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<section id="welcome-section">
  <h1 class="welcome-header">Hi, I'm Timothy McMasters</h1>
  <p class="welcome-para">an aspiring full-stack developer</p>
</section>
<section id="projects">
  <h2 class="projects-header">The following are projects that I have created</h2>
  <ul class="grid-container">
    <li class="grid-box">
      <a class="project-tile" href="https://codepen.io/tmmcmasters/full/QWOEXyO" target="_blank"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/3B42dcS/Form-Survey.png" class="project-image" alt="Form-Survey">Form Survey</img>
      </a>
    </li>

    <li class="grid-box">
      <a class="project-tile" href="https://codepen.io/tmmcmasters/full/zYPNdoX" target="_blank"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/wKLyykK/Product-Landing-Page.png" alt="Product-Landing-Page" class="project-image">Product Landing Page</img>
      </a>
    </li>

    <li class="grid-box">
      <a class="project-tile" href="https://codepen.io/tmmcmasters/full/MWOmaGJ" target="_blank" class="project-tile"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/0mdYX9X/Techncacal-Documentation-Page.png" alt="Technical-Documentation-Page" class="project-image">Technical Documentation Page</img>
      </a>
    </li>

    <li class="grid-box">
      <a href="https://codepen.io/tmmcmasters/full/MWOebeo" target="_blank" class="project-tile"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/tcJcWsw/Tribute-Page.png" alt="Tribute-Page" class="project-image">Tribute Page</img>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</section>
<section id="contact">
  <h2 id="contact-header">Contact Me</h2>
  <div class="contact-links">
    <ul>
      <li><a id="profile-link" href="https://github.com/Tmmcmasters" target="_blank">Github</a></li>
      <li><a id="profile-link" href="mailto:tmmcmasters@gmail.com?subject=" feedback " target="_blank ""> Email me </a></li>
      <li><a id="profile-link" href="tel:12602672147" target="_blank">Call me</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Remove the 40px padding-left from your `ul´ in `#projects`.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `padding: 0;` to your `grid-container` to remove the padding which makes the page scroll:

This is the code:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=PT+Sans&family=Roboto:wght@400;500&family=Ubuntu&display=swap');
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 62.5%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(180deg, #001219, #005F73, #0A9396, #0B9669);
}

body {
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  font-family: Roboto, PT Sans, Ubuntu;
  text-size-adjust: 80%;
}

#navbar {
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, #001219, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.navbar-links {
  text-decoration: none!important;
  color: #F2E9E4;
}

ul {
  list-style: none!important;
}

nav>ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.invisible-para {
  opacity: 0%;
}

#welcome-section {
  color: #CA6702;
  text-shadow: 2px, 2px;
  text-align: center;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 5vmin;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 13.5em;
}

.welcome-header {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 20px black;
}

.welcome-para {
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 20px black;
}

.project-image {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.projects-header {
  padding-top: 3rem!important;
  padding-bottom: 2rem;
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 3.5rem;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 20px black;
  color: #CA6702;
}

#projects {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.project-tile {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #001219;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 20px;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-family: PT Sans;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: #94D2BD;
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 300px;
  padding: 1rem;
  margin: 8vh 10vw 0 10vw;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 20px;
}

.grid-container {
  width: 100%;
  display: grid!important;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 2rem;
  align-self: center;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0; /* added this one */
}

#contact {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 3em;
  height: auto;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 20px;
}

#contact-header {
  font-size: 8vmin;
  padding: 0 0 2em 0;
}

div>ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

#profile-link {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  font-family: Ubuntu;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 4vmin;
  background-color: #94D2BD;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 8px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 20px;
}


/*MEDIA QUIERIES BELOW*/

@media (max-width: 800px) {
  .grid-container {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  }
}

@media (max-width:400px) {
  #welcome-section {
    bottom: 25em;
  }
}


/*MEDIA QUEIRIES ABOVE*/
```

```html
<p class="invisible-para" id="welcome-section"></p>
<nav id="navbar">
  <ul>
    <li><a class="navbar-links" href="#welcome-section">Welcome</a></li>
    <li><a class="navbar-links" href="#projects">Projects</a></li>
    <li><a class="navbar-links" href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<section id="welcome-section">
  <h1 class="welcome-header">Hi, I'm Timothy McMasters</h1>
  <p class="welcome-para">an aspiring full-stack developer</p>
</section>
<section id="projects">
  <h2 class="projects-header">The following are projects that I have created</h2>
  <ul class="grid-container">
    <li class="grid-box">
      <a class="project-tile" href="https://codepen.io/tmmcmasters/full/QWOEXyO" target="_blank"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/3B42dcS/Form-Survey.png" class="project-image" alt="Form-Survey">Form Survey</img>
      </a>
    </li>

    <li class="grid-box">
      <a class="project-tile" href="https://codepen.io/tmmcmasters/full/zYPNdoX" target="_blank"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/wKLyykK/Product-Landing-Page.png" alt="Product-Landing-Page" class="project-image">Product Landing Page</img>
      </a>
    </li>

    <li class="grid-box">
      <a class="project-tile" href="https://codepen.io/tmmcmasters/full/MWOmaGJ" target="_blank" class="project-tile"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/0mdYX9X/Techncacal-Documentation-Page.png" alt="Technical-Documentation-Page" class="project-image">Technical Documentation Page</img>
      </a>
    </li>

    <li class="grid-box">
      <a href="https://codepen.io/tmmcmasters/full/MWOebeo" target="_blank" class="project-tile"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/tcJcWsw/Tribute-Page.png" alt="Tribute-Page" class="project-image">Tribute Page</img>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</section>
<section id="contact">
  <h2 id="contact-header">Contact Me</h2>
  <div class="contact-links">
    <ul>
      <li><a id="profile-link" href="https://github.com/Tmmcmasters" target="_blank">Github</a></li>
      <li><a id="profile-link" href="mailto:tmmcmasters@gmail.com?subject=" feedback " target="_blank ""> Email me </a></li>
      <li><a id="profile-link" href="tel:12602672147" target="_blank">Call me</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</section>
```